# How do I make a custom ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to include an image within the `<a>` tag of an ActionLink. What is the best way to do this?

The final rendered link should look like this,

```
<a href="/Home/Test"><img src="test.jpg" />Test</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("...")"><img src="test.jpg" alt="test" />Test</a>
```